# polymer core-submenu alignment inside core-menu

Tags: polymer

I have a `core-menu` with `paper-item`s and a `core-submenu`. The `core-submenu` is aligned further left than the `paper-item`s and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong. Here is the code I'm using to generate the menu:

```
<core-menu
  valueattr="hash"
  selected="{{ route }}"
  selectedModel="{{ selectedPage }}">

  <template repeat="{{ menu }}">
    <template if="{{ submenu }}">
      <paper-submenu
        label="{{ name }}"
        icon="{{ icon }}"
        valueattr="hash"
        selected="{{ route }}"
        selectedModel="{{ selectedPage }}">

        <template repeat="{{ submenu }}">
          <paper-item hash="#{{ path }}" label="{{ name }}">
            <a href="#{{ path }}"></a>
          </paper-item>
        </template>
      </paper-submenu>
    </template>
    <template if="{{ !submenu }}">
      <paper-item hash="#{{ path }}" label="{{ name }}" icon="{{ icon }}">
        <a href="#{{ path }}"></a>
      </paper-item>
    </template>
  </template>
</core-menu>
```

Am I missing something? I could probably figure it out given more time, but time is of the essence.

**Edit:**

Per the IRC room, the `core-submenu` uses a `core-item` while I'm using `paper-item`s. So, I did a bit of copy-paste and replace to create a `paper-submenu` that uses a `paper-item`, it looks right, but it doesn't behave as I would expect. It's like items and submenus weren't meant to be used in tandem. Again, I'm not sure if it's a hookup issue or if I'm doing something wrong.

**Edit:**

Updating code. Still having weird issues.